# SQLAlchemy Style 2.X Problem Selected Column

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want select column in sqlalchemy and return result with fastapi

I run this query :

```
stmt = select(OrderAllocate)
return session.scalars(stmt).all()
```

Worked and return list object

Now i want return list object just two field and i use this command:

```
stmt = select(OrderAllocate.quantity, OrderAllocate.stock_id)
return session.execute(stmt).all()
```

return list tuple but i want list object becuse touple problem return with fastapi

Comment: What do you mean? What data structure would you expect back?

Comment: @M.O. I want this `select(OrderAllocate.quantity, OrderAllocate.stock_id)` return object similar `select(OrderAllocate)` but return tuple

Comment: If you want the ORM object, why do you not use the first query? If you are worried about unneccesary network traffic, look into "deferred column loading" and the `load_only` option.

Comment: @M.O. My full query is this : `select(OrderAllocate.stock_id, func.sum(OrderAllocate.quantity)).group_by(OrderAllocate.stock_id)`

Comment: Well, if your query contains aggregations (whcih you really should have put in the question), then you’re probably gonna have to package the data yourself.

Comment: try this `smt = select(func.sum(OrderAllocate.c.quantity),OrderAllocate.c.stock_id).group_by(OrderAllocate.c.stock_id) `